# Cognito - Emails not being sent after importing users

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have imported a csv file with users in an AWS Cognito User Pool. The users have email addresses with the **email_verified** attribute checked as TRUE and the **phone_verified** attribute checked as FALSE. The import job is successful, however, no email is being automatically sent out to the users with a reset code. I have looked into the AWS documentation and it states:

*In order for users to reset their passwords, they must have a verified email or phone number. Amazon Cognito sends a message containing a reset password code to the email or phone number specified in the .csv file. If the message is sent to the phone number, it is sent via SMS.*

Would this be an issue with the User Import role? I am using a role that was automatically created by the import job.

Here is my csv, just an example:

cognito:username,name,given_name,family_name,middle_name,nickname,preferred_username,profile,picture,website,email,email_verified,gender,birthdate,zoneinfo,locale,phone_number,phone_number_verified,address,updated_at,cognito:mfa_enabled

John,John,John,Doe,,,,,,,johndoe@example.com,TRUE,,,,,,FALSE,,,FALSE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, why you made the `cognito:mfa_enabled` but the user's mobile phones are unverified?

All users need to set their password, as Cognito does not allow password imports. And for this, you need to assign true to `RESET_REQUIRED`.

If you have small number of users you can reset the user's password through the web console: click on the user and the option is on the top. Or alternatively, you can use the AWS CLI as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cognito-idp/admin-reset-user-password.html).

**Reseting Passwords**
If you have a large number of users and you don't want to press the 'Reset Password' (obviously), you need to have a web application/API to do this for you. Because every time the user wants to reset the password, she will get a confirmation code from Cognito. You need to have a work flow in place.

After you have the above work flow working, you need to get the list of usernames using the Cognito API, put it in a List, and then send a request one by one.

Also, in Python you could use Boto, read about [reseting user passwords as an admin](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cognito-idp.html#CognitoIdentityProvider.Client.admin_reset_user_password).

Answer (score 2):

Just to put this here; Import creation job won't send email notification.
You've implemented a nice way to achieve your goal.